# Rust: Receive from channel in DrawingArea::connect_draw?

Tags: rust, gtk

I'm trying to make a program in which a window displays the changing state of a simulation. My idea for how to do this (and I'm very open to other suggestions) is to spawn off a thread which handles the simulation logic, and send messages detailing the state which are read in the draw handler. My current attempt at this looks like:

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate rand;
extern crate gtk;
extern crate gdk;
use std::{thread, time};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea};
use std::sync::mpsc;
fn main(){

    let (tx, rx )= mpsc::channel();

    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();
    app.connect_activate(|app| {
    let draw_area = DrawingArea::new();
    let _id = draw_area.connect_draw(|_unused, f| {
        let red : f64 = rx.recv().unwrap();
        f.set_source_rgb(red, 0.0, 0.0);
        f.paint().expect("Painting failed");
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .default_width(320)
        .default_height(200)
        .title("Hello, World!")
        .build();
    win.add(&draw_area);

    win.connect_event(|w, _g|{ //Placeholder until I learn to make queue_draw fire on a timer
        w.queue_draw();
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    win.show_all();
    });
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for _i in 0..9 {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
            tx.send(rand::random::<f64>()).unwrap();
        }

    });
    app.run();
}
```

This fails because `rx` does not live long enough. I think I understand why the compiler thinks that, but I'm not clear how to resolve the issue, or if this is a viable approach to begin with.

As a bonus question, there's an absolute hack in this code with the `win.connect_event` call, which lets me trigger a redraw by any action. I want that to just trigger at regular intervals, but I haven't found a way to do that yet - any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the stimulation to be non-blocking?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean, but I think you're referring to the `rx.recv` call blocking until there's something to receive? I actually don't care if it blocks or not, for the time being - there isn't any I/O it will be responsible for other than displaying the simulation.

Comment: By "blocking", I mean that the GUI can't do anything while `thread::sleep()` is running. I _think_ I have a blocking solution here; I'll post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - I thought I was only calling `thread::sleep` in a separate thread. Why would that impact the GUI?

Comment: It wouldn't. You said in your question that `rx` is causing the problem, and in the comments that you didn't care whether the solution blocked the GUI or not. Hence it seemed to me that the simplest solution was to remove the thread altogether. However, if you want to keep the thread, I'll try to see if I can get it to work. Either way is fine with me; it's really a matter of your preference.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think eventually I'll want multiple threads for performance reasons, but for now a single-threaded approach might work. All of my attempts at that caused all of the "simulation" logic to run and *then* the final state to be displayed, though, rather than showing a changing state. (Nothing is displayed until `app.run();` and `app.run()` only returns when the window closes.)

Comment: I'll get to work on it now. By the way, it can make it a lot easier on other users to include the imports when posting your code; I suggest you do that in the future.

Comment: Good point, added those

Comment: Well, I hate to disappoint you, but I haven't found a solution. There are so many questions about this problem out there, each specific to it's own code and conditions; it's hard to get a general idea of how you should go about fixing this. Unfortunately I don't know enough Rust to know how to fix this off the top of my head, and all my searches/fix attempts haven't really turned up anything I can translate to this specific situation :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way (asking [Rust: Why can't I move a value twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642006/rust-why-cant-i-move-a-value-twice) ) along the way. Describing what I learned:

- `rx` must be `moved` into a closure that uses it, if the closure might outlive the original scope in which `rx` was created. (This happens twice in the code in the question).
- This code has two nested closures, with `rx` created outside of each. You can "give" `rx` to the outer closure, but it cannot then give it to the inner one, because the outer one might be called repeatedly (for all rust knows). If it gives away its only copy, it might not have one for second calls, which would be unsafe.

My solution has been to define the `connect_draw` enclosure outside of the `connect_activate` closure. Note that this solution still isn't perfect as I haven't figure dout how to trigger `connect_draw` on a timer like a grown up, but the channel issue seems to be solved:

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate rand;
extern crate gtk;
extern crate gdk;
extern crate glib;
use std::{thread, time};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};


fn main(){
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();
    let (tx, rx ) : (Sender<f64>, Receiver<f64>)= mpsc::channel();
    gtk::init().expect("GTK init failed");
    let draw_area = DrawingArea::new();
    let _id = draw_area.connect_draw(move |_unused, f| {
        let red = rx.recv().unwrap();
        f.set_source_rgb(red,0.5, 0.5);
        f.paint().expect("Painting failed");
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    app.connect_activate(move |app| {
        let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();
        win.add(&draw_area);

        win.show_all();

        win.connect_event(|w, _g|{ //HORRIBLE HACK HELP FIX
            w.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(false)
        });
    });
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
            tx.send(rand::random::<f64>()).unwrap();
        }
    });
    app.run();
}
```