# Rust: Why can't I move a value twice?

Tags: rust, gtk, borrow-checker

New to Rust, really feel like I'm missing something here.

In the below code, there are two nested closures which are important to the question: `app.connect_activate` and `draw_area.connect_draw`. I am trying to use a channel to send values into the `connect_draw` closure, so that what is drawn will reflect the state of a simulation that changes over time (currently represented by random colors).

What I've found is very weird to me and I do not understand at all:

- if I create the channel within `connect_activate`, I can call `rx.recv` within `connect_draw` (this is the first example below)
- if I create the channel outside of `connect_activate`, I can call `rx.recv` within `connect_activate` (example omitted for brevity)
- if I create the channel outside of `connect_activate`, I *cannot* call `rx.recv` within `connect_draw`; it fails with `cannot move out of rx, a captured variable in an Fn closure` (this is the second example below)

In other words: I can move the created channel across either closure boundary, but not both. It can move from the scope of `main` into the scope of `connect_activate`, or from the scope of `connect_activate` into the scope of `connect_draw`, but it cannot do both in sequence. Why would this be the case? If I can move it into `connect_activate`, shouldn't it then be just as "owned" as if it were created there? Both cases do seem to be truly "moved", insofar as they fail if I omit the "move" keyword. What's going on here?

Bonus question: There's a hideous placeholder where I'm re-drawing every time I get any event, because I still don't know how to run events off a timer. Halp?

**Example 1: (WORKS)**

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate rand;
extern crate gtk;
extern crate gdk;
extern crate glib;
use std::{thread, time};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};


fn main(){
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();
    app.connect_activate(move |app| {
        let (tx, rx ) : (Sender<f64>, Receiver<f64>)= mpsc::channel();
        let draw_area = DrawingArea::new();
        let _id = draw_area.connect_draw(move |_unused, f| {
            let red = rx.recv().unwrap();
            let green = rx.recv().unwrap();
            let blue = rx.recv().unwrap();
            f.set_source_rgb(red,green, blue);
            f.paint().expect("Painting failed");
            Inhibit(false)
        });
        let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();
        win.add(&draw_area);

        win.show_all();
        
        win.connect_event(|w, _g|{ //Placeholder until I learn to make queue_draw fire on a timer
            w.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(false)
        });
        thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
                tx.send(rand::random::<f64>()).unwrap();
            }
        });
    });
    app.run();
}
```

**Example 2 (DOES NOT WORK)**

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate rand;
extern crate gtk;
extern crate gdk;
extern crate glib;
use std::{thread, time};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, DrawingArea};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};


fn main(){
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();
    let (tx, rx ) : (Sender<f64>, Receiver<f64>)= mpsc::channel();
    app.connect_activate(move |app| {
        let draw_area = DrawingArea::new();
        let _id = draw_area.connect_draw(move |_unused, f| {
            let red = rx.recv().unwrap();
            let green = rx.recv().unwrap();
            let blue = rx.recv().unwrap();
            f.set_source_rgb(red,green, blue);
            f.paint().expect("Painting failed");
            Inhibit(false)
        });
        let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();
        win.add(&draw_area);

        win.show_all();
        
        win.connect_event(|w, _g|{ //Placeholder until I learn to make queue_draw fire on a timer
            w.queue_draw();
            Inhibit(false)
        });
    });
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
            tx.send(rand::random::<f64>()).unwrap();
        }
    });
    app.run();
}
```

Comment: "does not work" is not very descriptive. You you get a compiler error? If so, please include it in full.

Comment: clone clone clone

Comment: @kmdreko D'oh. Added the error ("cannot move out of `rx`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure")

Comment: @Stargateur Are you saying my question is a duplicate, or that I should solve it by cloning `rx`? If the latter, how? `clone` isn't implemented for Receiver (I think for thread safety reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gtk application's [`connect_activate()`](https://docs.rs/gtk/latest/gtk/struct.Application.html#method.connect_activate) method takes in a `Fn` parameter, meaning it can be called multiple times. You cannot `move` a captured variable out of a `Fn` closure since the variable will have been moved next time you tried to call it. The first example works because it only moves a local variable that would be created each time.

Comment: Okay, cool, that makes perfect sense. So is there a right way to do something like this? I was playing around with trying to force the lifetime to be static but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Update: Realized nothing was really forcing me to define these as nested closures, which seems to solve the issue. Still curious what your solution would be, just in the interests of graduating from "it works" to "good".

Comment: @EdwardPeters unfortunately I'm not really familiar with the gtk lifecycle or best practices to give any real design advice :/

Comment: If you need nested closures like this, the solution is usually to use shared ownership, i.e. `std::rc::Rc` and cloning a new reference into the closures.